# Changing hostname of VPS - ZPanel Issue

Tags: apache, dns, centos, vps, hostname

Basically I've got a VPS setup but I incorrectly set the hostname. I left it for a while and it was fine, installed zpanel etc and now it's a 'web host' and everything was fine. Now I want to change the hostname so I logged into the hosting companies control panel for the server and changed the hostname.

The original and the new hostname are in the format of xxx.yyy.com. So nothing happend and I could still reach the zpanel login page via the 'old' host name even though in the hosting companies control panel it said it had changed.

For ease of explanation, we shall say my old hostname was xyz.example-domain.com and my new is server.another-domain.com. Both domains are controlled within this installation of zpanel.

Anyway. I deleted the dns entry for "xyz" on example-domain and, as you would expect, if you go to xyz.example-domain.com you get nothing. I created a dns A record for server.another-domain.com but now all you get is the default apache 'welcome to your server' page. To get to zpanel login, you need the IP address.

SO my question is, do I need to do something else? It seems that I need to change where this zpanel login page is getting displayed so that it can be server.another-domain.com. I'm guessing there is some file somewhere that I need to edit but I don't know what one and "the internet" isn't really helping as all I find is 'change the host name in the hosting companies control panel' which I've done.

PS It is an apache 2 server running CentOS 6

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your Apache configuration located in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. If you intend on running multiple domains off the same host, you'll need to setup Virtual Hosts. You'll see a detailed explanation of those settings toward the bottom of your configuration file.

Depending on where you've located your files, you'll want to set your DocumentRoot accordingly for each of your Virtual Hosts, and that will instruct Apache to look for the files in the proper places. By default, I believe it looks in `/var/www`.

NOTE: You will need to restart Apache or reload configurations whenever you alter your configuration file. You can do this by running either one of the following commands (as root):

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
/etc/init.d/httpd reload
```

Comment: Virtual Hosting was setup by Zpanel it seems, it's all ready to go and multiple domains are running just fine (i.e. the server currently has 3 websites up on it and they all work with no problems) 

I can SSH to the server if I use the new hostname (server.example-domain.com) and if you go there you get this default apache page, plus in the hosting companies control panel for the VPS it says it's server.example-domain.com. 

SO I'm pretty sure that the hostname has been changed, example-domain.com has an A entry for 'server' so I'm pretty sure that I just need to change something in Zpanel :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with zpanel, but maybe you just need to restart it so it picks up the configuration changes you've made, much like you'd have to do with other services running on CentOS. Look in your `/etc/init.d` directory for a zpanel service and if one exists, restart it (ie `/etc/init.d/zpanel restart`) and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **/etc/zpanel/panel/**

rename: **index.php** -->**panel.php** (or any other name).

Then create **index.php** and let it in blank (or write a welcome message)

Finally enter to your zpanel like this: *http://www.yourIP/panel.php*

Works fine!

***Is not necessary change any port***